# Unable to call jsp pages using ejs and express in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsp

Here is my app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;.
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
require('./config')(app, io);
require('./routes')(app, io);
console.log('Your application is running on http://localhost:' + port);
```

Here is my config.js

```
var express = require('express');
module.exports = function(app, io){
app.set('view engine', 'jsp');
app.engine('jsp', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
io.set('log level', 1);
};
```

Here is my routes.js

```
var gravatar = require('gravatar');
module.exports = function(app,io){

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    res.render('home');
});

app.get('/create', function(req,res){


    var id = Math.round((Math.random() * 1000000));

    res.redirect('/chatting/'+id);
});

app.get('/chatting/:id', function(req,res){


    res.render('chatting');

});

app.get('/iframekapage', function(req,res){


    res.render('iframekapage');
});

var chat = io.of('/socket').on('connection', function (socket) {



    socket.on('load',function(data){

        if(chat.clients(data).length === 0 ) {

            socket.emit('peopleinchat', {number: 0});
        }
        else if(chat.clients(data).length === 1) {

            socket.emit('peopleinchat', {
                number: 1,
                user: chat.clients(data)[0].username,
                avatar: chat.clients(data)[0].avatar,
                id: data
            });
        }
        else if(chat.clients(data).length >= 2) {

            chat.emit('tooMany', {boolean: true});
        }
    });

    socket.on('login', function(data) {


        if(chat.clients(data.id).length < 2){


            socket.username = data.user;
            socket.room = data.id;
            socket.avatar = gravatar.url(data.avatar, {s: '140', r: 'x', d: 'mm'});


            socket.emit('img', socket.avatar);



            socket.join(data.id);

            if(chat.clients(data.id).length == 2) {

                var usernames = [],
                    avatars = [];

                usernames.push(chat.clients(data.id)[0].username);
                usernames.push(chat.clients(data.id)[1].username);

                avatars.push(chat.clients(data.id)[0].avatar);
                avatars.push(chat.clients(data.id)[1].avatar);




                chat.in(data.id).emit('startChat', {
                    boolean: true,
                    id: data.id,
                    users: usernames,
                    avatars: avatars
                });
            }

        }
        else {
            socket.emit('tooMany', {boolean: true});
        }
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function() {


        socket.broadcast.to(this.room).emit('leave', {
            boolean: true,
            room: this.room,
            user: this.username,
            avatar: this.avatar
        });


        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });



    socket.on('msg', function(data){


        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('receive', {msg: data.msg, user: data.user, img: data.img});
    });
 });
  };
```

I don't know what problem am I facing, I have changed the **.html** to **.jsp** in `config.js` but stll it is throwing errors like this:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "home" in views directory "C:\Users\admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\nodejsproject\web/views"
```

I don't know why am I getting these error.

Could this be due to `ejs` I am using ?